# Upgrade GCC to 9.2 in Deepin

Tags: gcc, deepin

I newly installed Deepin 15.11  which comes with gcc 6.2. I tried to upgrade gcc and g++ to last release 9.2.

As I read from the net, it is advised to not use ubuntu ppa to due to mix iwth debian (on which deepin is based) and ubuntu.

I tried to figure out how and where I could get a ppa for debian but with no success.

So pls how could I uopgrade gcc on my deepin to 9.2.

thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, the Debian testing version (bullseye) has GCC 9.2. I can't say how compatible this will be with your system but if you want GCC provided by a package manager and you must have 9.2 and you must use Debian (form), then the only option is a testing version which may not be stable.

Comment: In your case, the best way to get GCC 9.2 is to build it from source. It's not a good idea to install packages from the repos of another distribution.